beanie migrate command throwing ModuleNotFoundError even though I put __init__.py files in respective directories
I was looking into beanie migrations documentation. While importing my documents from models.py file like from app.models.users import User, vs code does not show me any error. But when I run the beanie migrate command, it throws a trackback message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named app. I put the __init__.py file while creating the respective directories. FastAPI runs welll with it.
Here is how the migrations.py file was written:
from app.models.users import User

class Forward:
    ...


class Backward:
    ...

This is the command I ran:
beanie migrate -uri 'mongodb://user:pass@host' -db db -p relative/path/to/migrations/directory/

And this what I got after execution:
Building migration list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alexpy/Desktop/backend/env/bin/beanie", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(migrations())
  File "/home/alexpy/Desktop/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alexpy/Desktop/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/alexpy/Desktop/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/alexpy/Desktop/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/alexpy/Desktop/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alexpy/Desktop/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/beanie/executors/migrate.py", line 200, in migrate
    asyncio.run(run_migrate(settings))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/alexpy/Desktop/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/beanie/executors/migrate.py", line 110, in run_migrate
    root = await MigrationNode.build(settings.path)
  File "/home/alexpy/Desktop/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/beanie/migrations/runner.py", line 222, in build
    ).load_module((path / name).stem)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 548, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1063, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 888, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 290, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 719, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/alexpy/Desktop/backend/app/migrations/20240901100154_users_alter_name.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app.models.users import User
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

 - List item


Here is how my file hierarchy looks like:
app/
├── __init__.py
├── models/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── users.py
├── migrations/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── 202409011004_user_0001.py
└── main.py


I looked into the migration example files as well. There, the document classes were rewritten in the migration files.
Do I need to rewrite my model classes in the migrations.py file every time I need to migrate?

In addition to the link provided above, please take a look here and here as well.
